# iPhone, how to got the lines count of the UITextView text content?

Tags: iphone

all, as topic, I want know the lines count of the UITextView,  because I do not want user use scorll bar to scrolling the content , so I want split the content to multi-sub content to show in the UITextView in order .

thanks for helping .

Regards

Answer (score 0):

See this post: [Limiting text in UITextView](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/411398/limiting-text-in-a-uitextview). Check one of the answers.

Comment: thanks for tip..... but the problem is that if the content is exist, it just set to the TextViw.text , so how to split it ......