# How to restrict UITextView in 2 lines?

Tags: iphone, uitextview

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Limit the number of lines for UITextview](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5225763/limit-the-number-of-lines-for-uitextview)

Can any one guide me, how to restrict UITextView with only 2 lines? In my project I have to use textview but with only two lines and i don't know how to do it.
Please help !

Comment: Read this
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5225763/limit-the-number-of-lines-for-uitextview

Answer (score -1):

Like this but then door UITextView i guess:

```
// Putting a small label with some basic information on screen
UILabel *infoLabel = [[UILabel alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(10, 10, 300, 800)];
infoLabel.numberOfLines = 2;
```

Comment: but label will not work like UITextView i think

Comment: The question was about a UITextView not a UILabel. UITextView does not have such a think as numberOfLines.

Comment: This is just plain wrong.