# Display string with more than 3000 chars in label view Xcode

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode

My app need to display string value in label the string value is get from web server its length exceeds upto 3000 char

My code is

```
    [super viewDidLayoutSubviews];
    [self.scrollview layoutIfNeeded];
    self.scrollview.contentSize = self.contentview.bounds.size;
    [self.scrollview1 layoutIfNeeded];
    self.scrollview1.contentSize = self.label_sample.bounds.size;
    [self.scrolllabel layoutIfNeeded];
    self.scrolllabel.contentSize = self.textlabelscroll.bounds.size;
    [self.scrolllabel addSubview:textlabelscroll];
}

-(void)viewDidLoad

{

 [textlabelscroll setText:(got from webserver)];

 [textlabelscroll sizeToFit];

}
```

the label displays empty but the scroll is enabled am unable to view the string if the string length is more than 934 characters.

Comment: Please take a look at [`UITextView`](https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UITextView_Class/index.html)

Comment: I want to display in single line

Comment: `UITextView` lets you control the number of lines ([link](http://stackoverflow.com/a/21149287/335858)).

Comment: This not working for me actually the label is inside a table view cell

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My Suggestion it maybe correct or not... try text view or why you need label and add this

```
- (BOOL)textFieldShouldBeginEditing:(UITextField *)textField{
return NO;}
```

or

```
[textView setEditable:NO];
```

To disable editing textview

Why you want only label???

Comment: since this should be in single line