# Limit Lines of UITextView

Tags: ios, xcode, swift

I'm trying to limit the maximum lines of my textview to 2 lines.  Ive tried:

This allows returns on the 3rd line

```
 func textViewDidChange(textView: UITextView) { 

  let  numLines:CGFloat = textView.contentSize.height/textView.font.lineHeight;
    if (numLines > 2.999999)
    {
       textView.text = textView.text.substringToIndex(advance(textView.text.endIndex, -1))
    }        
}
```

This has some weird behavior on returns

```
textView.textContainer.maximumNumberOfLines = 2;
```

Any suggestions on how I can limit my textview to two lines?

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
textView.maxNumberOfLines = 2
```

Comment: that code doesnt work unless I put textContainer inbetween them and I've already tried that

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/27793974/3983725 this answer worked for me, just add textView.textContainer.lineBreakMode = NSLineBreakMode.ByTruncatingTail, after setting the maximumNumberOfLines

Comment: maximumNumberOfLines has weird behavior.  After returning the maximum amount of times and then typing again it writes more text above the first line

Comment: While this might answer the question, without any explanation it will stay at best marginal. In point of fact, it was auto-flagged as VLQ for that reason.