# Use Storyboard to set maximum number of lines for UITextView like UILabel?

Tags: ios, storyboard, uilabel, uitextview

In Storyboard, is it possible to set the maximum number of lines in a `UITextView` similar to how you can with a `UILabel`? All the other SO posts only show programmatic solutions.

Comment: As per my experience this is not possible.

Comment: Duplicate:[Limit the number of lines for UITextview](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5225763/limit-the-number-of-lines-for-uitextview#answer-27793974)

Comment: Yes it is possible to set number of lines of UItextView like UILabel

Comment: No it is not. Create an outlet and set it by code.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can do it with `User Defined Runtime Attributes` for this view. Select your `UITextView`, open *Identity inspector*, and add new attribute. Enter `textContainer.maximumNumberOfLines` to `key path`, select `Number` as type and put your number to `Value` field.

[image]

Answer (score -1):

First of all make Text as "Attributed" and then select button which is shown in below image..[image]

It may be helpful to you.. Thanks..

Comment: How is this helpful? Saying it "may be helpful" is not answering the question.