# iPhone: Limiting text input in an UITextView

Tags: iphone, objective-c, uitextview

I am trying to limit the amount of LINES a user can have in an UITextView. Let's consider I only want to allow 4 lines (i.e. in the following example, you can't go higher than a height of 84 pixels with the given font in a given UITextView with a width of 200).

I coded this to achieve the limiting and it works fine:

```
    - (BOOL)textView:(UITextView *)aTextView shouldChangeTextInRange:(NSRange)aRange replacementText:(NSString *)aText {

    NSString* newText = [aTextView.text stringByReplacingCharactersInRange:aRange withString:aText];


    CGSize strSize = [newText sizeWithFont:textView.font constrainedToSize:CGSizeMake(200, 10000) lineBreakMode:UILineBreakModeWordWrap];

if (strSize.height > 100)

    {

        return NO; // can't enter more text
    }
    else
        return YES; // let the textView know that it should handle the inserted text
    }
```

So far so good. The problem starts when I try to be sneaky and enter as many 'x's as I can before each return. In that case, I can get an extra of 4 lines... which I obviously do not want to allow. I assume that this has something to do with the lineBreakMode? Is there any case to alter this? I haven't found much in the docs (but then again, I usually have a hard time understanding them).

I attached a couple of screenshots to illustrate the problem. I'd be grateful for any suggestions. Thanks a lot!

---

[image: Normal behaviour - stops after 4 lines]
[image: Deviant behaviour - too many lines through additional x-es]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

*(I hope I understood your problem correctly... )*

If you look closely, there's a margin in `UITextView`. If you use `sizeWithFont:` carelessly, it can return unexpected results in special cases (because you disrespect the text view's margin).

You should either 1) adjust the width you use in `sizeWithFont:` to respect the text view's margin or 2) use an auxiliary `UITextView` object to accurately compute the content size.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your thoughts. Do you know how I find out what the exact margin is? Is it just something to experiment with?

Comment: ryyst: This actually WORKS! thanks so much, you were right. It's all down to reducing the 200 a bit. Still, I'm wondering if there is a way to find out the margins programatically and not by guessing.

Comment: @n.evermind: I don't know whether you can find out the margins programmatically - I don't think it is possible using public APIs. By the way, option 2 is described on Apple's dev forums [here](http://discussions.apple.com/thread.jspa?threadID=1923059). (Oh, and make sure you accept this answer if it solved your problem :p)

Comment: sure! i didn't mark it first as I needed to wait for 15 minutes or so, but here we go. Thanks a lot again, this really helped!

Answer (score 1):

Looks to me like word wrapping is *on* in UITextView and there's not much you can do to change it (please tell me I am wrong).  If you want 4 lines only, maybe 4 UITextField's in a UIScrollView (sent the return key to Next).  Or reduce the ContentSize when the length of the render rectangle of each line exceeds the height of one line.

See also [limiting text in a uitextview](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/411398/limiting-text-in-a-uitextview)

Comment: Thanks, but I really need to use an UITextView. Don't really understand what you mean by reducing centensize? Also, the link you've provided (thanks for that!) suggestest that you could do a work around by reducing the width of the checked text, but then again, this isn't ideal. Thanks though for your time!